# Why does Bhavishya Puran say that Shiva or Vishnu can be glorified in front of each other but not in front of Durga?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, puranas, durga, bhavishya-purana

The Bhavisya Purāna has the following quote -

> वासुदेवामतश्चापि रुद्रमाहात्म्यवर्णनम् ।। रुद्राग्रे वासुदेवस्य
> कीर्तनं पुण्यवर्धनम् ।। 2.1.7.३० ।। दुर्गाग्रे शिवसूर्यस्य
> वैष्णवाख्यानमेव च ।। यः करोति विमूढात्मा गार्दभीं योनिमाविशेत् ।। ३१
> ।।
>
> Glorifying Rudra in front of Vāsudeva or Glorifying Vāsudeva in front
> of Rudra leads to attaining Punya.
>
> However the fool who  Glorifies Shiva, Surya or Vishnu in front of
> Durgā attains the birth of a Donkey.

Bhavisya Purāna, Madhyama parva, part-1, Chapter 7

My Question is If Shiva and Vishnu can be mutually glorified before each other why the exception for Durga?